# How to get data attribute value on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link and when is pressed the value of the text and data attribute of one div is changing.
I have another link when is pressed i get those changed values.
Here is the code:

```
<a class="first" href="#">change value</a>
<a class="second" href="#">get value</a>
<div class="value" data-test="test">test</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.first').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.value').html($(this).text()).attr('data-test',$(this).text());    
    });

    $('.second').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $value = $('.value').text();
        $data = $('.value').data('test');
        alert($data);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4daoqzc8/2/

The problem is that after value are changed i can get the new text value of the div but the value of the data attribute remains the same as was when the dom loaded.
How can i get the new value of the data attribute?

Comment: Set it the same way: `data('test', $(this).text())`. http://jsfiddle.net/4daoqzc8/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/4daoqzc8/8/ This?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will only retrieve the `data-test` attribute for the value `.data('test')` if it hasn't stored one already. So it offers the [`.removeData`](http://api.jquery.com/removeData) method, which you can call when you change the attribute to force jQuery to retrieve `.data('test')` from the attribute again next time:

```
$('.value').html($(this).text())
    .removeData('test')
    .attr('data-test', $(this).text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8mp6k2w2/

---

However, it would be better to just be consistent and use either `.attr()` or `.data()` to both set and get the value:

```
$('.value').html($(this).text())
    .data('test', $(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$data = $('.value').attr('data-test');
```

Comment: You should add an explanation about why your solution works but OP's doesn't (IIRC it's because jQuery uses it's on data store).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to set the value using the `data` function instead of `attr`:

```
$('.value').html($(this).text())
           .data('test', $(this).text());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bo3h469a/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$data = $('.value').data()['test'];
```

Here [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr) is more interesting topic for this.